# How to run parallel map_fn when eager execution enabled

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing

Consider the following tensorflow code snippet:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def fn(i):
    # do some junk work
    for _ in range(100):
        i ** 2
    return i

n = 1000
n_jobs = 8
stuff = np.arange(1, n + 1)
eager = False
t0 = time.time()
if eager:
    tf.enable_eager_execution()
res = tf.map_fn(fn, stuff, parallel_iterations=n_jobs)
if not eager:
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        res = sess.run(res)
        print(sum(res))
else:
    print(sum(res))
dt = time.time() - t0
print("(eager=%s) Took %ims" % (eager, dt * 1000))
```

If run with `eager = True` it is 10x slower than when run with `eager = False`. I did some prints, and found out that in `eager = True` mode, the `map_fn` call is running sequential, instead of spawning 8 parallel threads.

## Question

So my question is how to use `map_fn` (with parallel_iterations > 1) in eager execution mode ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I was using TF 2.3 for this, don't expect the same result with newer versions.)

More than an answer to OP's question, this is an extension of it, showing why the other answers are not addressing the real problem, because `tf.function` is not enough to force parallelism.

---

First, using `tf.function` does not force parallelization. It force tracing, and the construction of a graph, this happens just once, so, the `time.sleep()` used in other answers runs only the first time the tracing is necessary, that's why you see a speed up with `tf.function`. But you still don't see a difference when changing `parallel_iterations`.

Let's use a `py_fuction` to see the difference:

```py
def op(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    return 2 * x.numpy()

def op_tf(x):
    print('Tracing')
    return tf.py_function(op, [x], Tout=tf.int32)
```

Without using the decorator (or calling directly) `tf.function` any call to `op_tf` will always print "Tracing" (though in this cases is not tracing)

```
In [57]: op_tf(1)
Tracing
Out[57]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>

In [58]: op_tf(1)
Tracing
Out[58]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>
```

With `tf.function` we see Tracing just once (if we use the same arguments):

```py
In [67]: @tf.function
    ...: def op_tf(x):
    ...:     print("Tracing")
    ...:     return tf.py_function(op, [x], Tout=tf.int32)
    ...: 

In [68]: op_tf(1)
Tracing
Out[68]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>

In [69]: op_tf(2)
Tracing
Out[69]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=4>

In [70]: op_tf(3)
Tracing
Out[70]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=6>

In [71]: op_tf(3)
Out[71]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=6>
```

This happens because the function has to build a new graph for every new argument, if we pass directly a signature we avoid that happening:

```py
In [73]: @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.int32)])
    ...: def op_tf(x):
    ...:     print("Tracing")
    ...:     return tf.py_function(op, [x], Tout=tf.int32)
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [74]: op_tf(1)
Tracing
Out[74]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>

In [75]: op_tf(2)
Out[75]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=4>

In [76]: op_tf(3)
Out[76]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=6>
```

The same happens if we first call the method `get_concrete_function`:

```py
In [79]: @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.int32)])
    ...: def op_tf(x):
    ...:     print("Tracing")
    ...:     return tf.py_function(op, [x], Tout=tf.int32)
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [80]: op_tf = op_tf.get_concrete_function()
Tracing

In [81]: op_tf(1)
Out[81]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>

In [82]: op_tf(2)
Out[82]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=4>
```

Then, the answers claiming that just by adding `tf.function` is enough to get parallel execution is not fully correct:

```py
In [84]: def op(x):
    ...:     print("sleep")
    ...:     time.sleep(0.1)
    ...:     return 1.
    ...: 

In [85]: x = tf.ones(shape=(10,))

In [86]: _ = tf.map_fn(op, x, parallel_iterations=10)
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep

In [87]: @tf.function
    ...: def my_map(*args, **kwargs):
    ...:     return tf.map_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    ...: 

In [88]: my_map(op, x, parallel_iterations=10)
sleep
Out[88]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32)>
```

In comparison, if the python instructions for sleep and print are inside of a py_function they will be always called:

```py
In [96]: x = tf.ones(shape=(10,), dtype=tf.int32)

In [97]: def op(x):
    ...:     print("sleep")
    ...:     time.sleep(0.1)
    ...:     return 2 * x.numpy()
    ...: 

In [98]: @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.int32)])
    ...: def op_tf(x):
    ...:     print("Tracing")
    ...:     return tf.py_function(op, [x], Tout=tf.int32)
    ...: 

In [99]: _ = my_map(op_tf, x, parallel_iterations=1)
Tracing
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
```

Now, that we have somehow clear that Tracing of a function is giving us some confusions, let's remove the prints to time the calls:

```py
In [106]: def op(x):
     ...:     time.sleep(0.1)
     ...:     return 2 * x.numpy()
     ...: 

In [107]: @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.int32)])
     ...: def op_tf(x):
     ...:     return tf.py_function(op, [x], Tout=tf.int32)
     ...: 

In [108]: %timeit tf.map_fn(op_tf, x, parallel_iterations=1)
1.02 s ± 554 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [109]: %timeit tf.map_fn(op_tf, x, parallel_iterations=10)
1.03 s ± 509 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Running the following script and using tensorboard we can see exactly what's happening:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import time
from datetime import datetime

stamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
logdir = 'logs/func/%s' % stamp

# Start tracing.                                                                                                                                                                              
options = tf.profiler.experimental.ProfilerOptions(
    host_tracer_level=3, python_tracer_level=1, device_tracer_level=1, delay_ms=None
)

tf.profiler.experimental.start(logdir, options = options)

def op(x):
    x = x.numpy()
    start = time.time()

    while time.time() < start + x / 100:
        x = (2 * x) % 123

    return x

@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([], tf.int32)])
def op_tf(x):
    return tf.py_function(op, [x], Tout=tf.int32, name='op')

@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([None], tf.int32)])
def my_map(x):
    return tf.map_fn(op_tf, x, parallel_iterations=16)

x = tf.ones(100, tf.int32)
print(my_map(x))

tf.profiler.experimental.stop()
```

We get the following in Tensorboard:
[image]

The `py_function` is effectively using several threads but not in parallel. With `parallel_iterations=1` we obtain something similar
[image]

If we add at the beginning of the script the following

```py
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1)
tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(1)
```

we are forcing TF to use a single thread for all the graph computations:
[image]

So, at this moment we can only get some form of parallel execution if we set the inter/intra threads right.

If we disable Eager execution completely:

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(128)
tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(128)

stamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
logdir = f'logs/func/{stamp}'

tf.profiler.experimental.start(logdir)

def op(x):
    x = x.numpy()
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() < start + x / 100:
        x = (2 * x) % 123
    return x

@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([], tf.int32)])
def op_tf(x):
    return tf.py_function(op, [x], Tout=tf.int32, name='op')

# Create a placeholder.                                                                                                                                                                       
x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:

    writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)

    #tf.profiler.experimental.start(logdir, options = options)                                                                                                                                
    tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True)

    print(
        sess.run(
            [tf.map_fn(op_tf, x, parallel_iterations=16)],
            feed_dict={
                x: np.ones(4, dtype=np.int)
            }
        )
    )

tf.profiler.experimental.stop()
```

we can see now parallel executions in Tensorboard:
[image]

And if  we set to 1 the intra/inter threads and parallel_iterations we get the previous behaviuour back:
[image]

I hope this helps to clarify the role of `tf.function` in checking full parallelism.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and the insightful investigations. I've not read you answer in detail but I'll just go  ahead and accept it, as the graphs alone appear to give clear view of the bizarreries going on. Unfortunately, I left tensorflow for pytorch shortly: I found TF unnecessarily complex / complicated (it's closer to a bad operating system than to a machine learning library...)

Comment: This is superful and should have more upvotes. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Crudely speaking, `tf.map_fn(fn, data)` is essentially shorthand for:

```
for e in data:
  fn(e)
```

When eager execution is enabled, operations are executed as the Python interpreter encounters them, and thus there are no opportunities for "whole program optimizations".

When executing TensorFlow graphs, the TensorFlow runtime sees the complete computation to be executed and can thus apply optimizations such as "execute operations in `fn` from multiple iterations in the loop in parallel". This is one of the benefits of expressing the computation as a graph.

When eager execution in TensorFlow is enabled, you can still selectively apply graph optimizations to portions of your program using [`tf.contrib.eager.defun`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/defun).

For example (where most of the code is the same as yours above, and then a one line change to use `tf.contrib.eager.defun` to get graph optimization benefits):

```
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

def fn(i):
    # do some junk work
    for _ in range(100):
        i ** 2
    return i

n = 1000
n_jobs = 8
stuff = np.arange(1, n + 1)

def my_computation(x):
  return tf.map_fn(fn, x, parallel_iterations=n_jobs)

t0 = time.time()
my_computation(stuff)
dt = time.time() - t0
print("my_computation took %ims" % (dt * 1000))

my_computation = tf.contrib.eager.defun(my_computation)
# On the very first call, a graph is constructed, so let's discount
# graph construction time
_ = my_computation(stuff)

# And then time it
t0 = time.time()
my_computation(stuff)
dt = time.time() - t0
print("my_computation took %ims" % (dt * 1000))
```

Some additional things of note:

- In the particular example you've provided above, the TensorFlow runtime would probably also detect that `fn(i)` reduces to `return i` and can optimize away the unnecessary loop of `range(100)` since that does not affect the output. So the contrast in performance is quite a bit (as when executing `fn(i)` eagerly, the Python interpreter has no way of knowing that the `for` loop in there is useless, so it will execute that).
- If you change the computation in `fn()` to be something more meaningful, say:

  def fn(i):
    for _ in range(2):
      i = i ** 2
    return i

  then you'll see a less stark difference.
- Note that not everything that can be expressed in Python can be "defun"ed. See documentation for `tf.contrib.eager.defun` for some detail and a more detailed spec and implementation is proposed for TensorFlow 2.0 (see [RFC](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/pull/20))

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Update here for TF2.0 users. 
You can parallelize the call to tf.map_fn inner operator by wrapping it into a tf.function decorator:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

x = tf.ones(shape=(10,))

def op(x):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return 1.

_ = tf.map_fn(op, x, parallel_iterations=10) # will take 1 sec along with the 
                                             # warning message.

# Now wrap tf.map_fn inside tf.function
@tf.function
def my_map(*args, **kwargs):
    return tf.map_fn(*args, **kwargs)

_ = my_map(op, x, parallel_iterations=10) # will take 0.1 sec along with no 
                                          # warning message.
```

Comment: Do you see any difference if you change the parallel_iterations to 1 or traverse from 1 to 10? I tried locally and I see the same numbers even for `parallel_iterations=1`. There has to be something else in play that allows that parallelism, and the argument seems to be useless. I use TF2.3, can you explain that?

```python
In [27]: %timeit my_map(op, x, parallel_iterations=10)
1.92 ms ± 195 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [28]: %timeit my_map(op, x, parallel_iterations=1)
1.99 ms ± 147 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: So, this has nothing to do with parallel_iterations, what's happening here is that time.sleep is called only once, when the function is being traced, any subsequent call will skip the time.sleep call and run the op in the graph. If you use directly `get_concrete_function` you will have to wait a second, but it returns a function that does not have to wait.

Answer (score -1):

Let me udpate this question's answer on TF2.1.

Since TF2.x, when the computing graph description statements could be executed in eager mode, some of the tf functions could be executed in parallel as its naturally run in session mode.

One simple solution is using tf.function to convert those eager mode running python function to tf_function running mode(session) without channging the whole programming mode( from eager mode to session mode).

@Rémy Dubois solustion works fine in TF2.1.

```
@tf.function
def my_map(*args, **kwargs):
    return tf.map_fn(*args, **kwargs)

_ = my_map(op, x, parallel_iterations=10) # will take 0.1 sec along with no 
                                          # warning message.
```

And we also could dynamically change the my_map function by converting it with tf.function(), e.g.

```
def my_map(*args, **kwargs):
    return tf.map_fn(*args, **kwargs)

my_map=tf.function(my_map)
_ = my_map(op, x, parallel_iterations=10) # will take 0.1 sec along with no 
                                          # warning message.
```

Both above 2 solutions could work correctly in TF2.1 now.

And the warning message in TF2.x about the tf.map_fn() for parallel_iterations is wrong as:

```
Setting parallel_iterations > 1 has no effect when executing eagerly. Consider calling map_fn with tf.contrib.eager.defun to execute fn in parallel.
```

since tf.contrib.eager.defun is already changed to tf.function.