# tf.map_fn does not improve speed with higher parallel_iterations

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a custom loss function in which I need to evaluate a function over all values in a tensor. In order to parallelize this I am trying to use tf.map_fn method with `parallel_iterations` argument set to 8 (my cpu has 16 cores). However, I found that this hasn't improved the speed in computing loss irrespective of the value set to `parallel_iterations`.

For illustration the below code has the same execution time irrespective of the value given to `parallel_iterations`. What am I missing?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time
import numpy as np

def some_fn(x):
    return tf.math.exp(x)

@tf.function
def map_fn_test(samples):
    some_fn_vals = tf.map_fn(some_fn, samples, parallel_iterations=8)
    return some_fn_vals

samples = tf.constant(np.linspace(0,10,100000))
start_time = time.time()
values = map_fn_test(samples)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 1):

When executing eagerly, `map_fn` does not execute in parallel even if parallel_iterations is set to a value > 1. For more details on library find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn#eager_execution_2)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time
import numpy as np

def some_fn(x):
    return tf.math.exp(x)

@tf.function
def map_fn_test(samples):
    some_fn_vals = tf.map_fn(some_fn, samples, parallel_iterations=8)
    return some_fn_vals

samples = tf.constant(np.linspace(0,10,100000))
start_time = time.time()
values = map_fn_test(samples)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Output

```
--- 24.097240209579468 seconds ---
```

When we execute the code without the decorator (`@tf.function`) it takes more time,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time
import numpy as np

def some_fn(x):
    return tf.math.exp(x)


def map_fn_test(samples):
    some_fn_vals = tf.map_fn(some_fn, samples, parallel_iterations=8)
    return some_fn_vals

samples = tf.constant(np.linspace(0,10,100000))
start_time = time.time()
values = map_fn_test(samples)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Output

```
--- 87.56250762939453 seconds ---
```

Please go through similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52774351/how-to-run-parallel-map-fn-when-eager-execution-enabled)

Comment: However, executing with `@tf.function` but different `parallel_iterations` options (e.g. 1 and 8) takes the same amount of time. The time improvement in your example is likely attributed to `tf.function`.